# How to quickly delete all text in emacs' minibuffer?

Tags: emacs, editor, text-editor

I'm new to Emacs. I run emacs on Windows. When I start Emacs by click the `runemacs.exe`, I got a welcome window. Now to create a new file and do some experiment editing, I press <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd>. Now the minibuffer shows something similar to:

```
Find file: d:\emacs-23.3\bin
```

Normally I need to press backspace some time to delete `d:\emacs-23\bin` and type a new file name like `c:\test\a.txt`. My question is, how can I quickly delete `d:\emacs-23\bin`? How do you deal with the welcome window (I don't like it)?

Thanks

Comment: The question about the welcome window is really a separate question.  You shouldn't combine two unrelated questions just because you thought of them at the same time.  Post two questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to delete the default filename. Just continue to enter your file

```
d:\emacs-23.3\bin\c:\test\a.txt
```

Comment: Note that this only works with absolute paths, and only on Windows.

Comment: Correction of my comment above: you can achieve a similar behavior on Unix-like systems for absolute paths, too. Just make sure that you use two slashes to mark the beginning of the absolute path instead of just one which would be indistinguishable from a relative path.

Answer (score 12):

`backward-kill-sentence` is bound to <kbd>C-x DEL</kbd> by default.

Alternatively, you could type <kbd>C-a C-k</kbd> which I find slightly easier to type because

1. you don't have to release the CTRL key before hitting the third key.
2. your right hand does not have to leave the home row

This key combination first moves point (aka the cursor) to the beginning of the line, and then kills the line. So it's actually two commands, but it's the same amount of key strokes.

Comment: +1 *C-a C-k* for me too... And both C-a and C-k are useful in a lot of other situations :)

Comment: C-a C-k in the find-file prompt will replace your most recent kill and will thrash your kill ring with superfluous paths. Just appending an absolute path at the end has no side effects and is the simplest to perform.

Comment: Whether that's superfluous or not depends on the situation. You can always retrieve the previous kill with `yank-pop`. It's true that just typing an absolute path is even simpler to perform and probably what the poster was after (hence it's the accepted answer) but it does not actually answer the question as written.

Comment: I like to use c-e c-u, but the idea is the same

Comment: `C-u` is normally used for prefix arguments `(universal-argument)`, did you rebind it to something else?

Answer (score 4):

On unix-like OSes, you can type `~` or `/` *after* the file- or pathname in the prompt. Emacs then takes that as the starting point for the file path. `~` starts from your home directory, `/` from root.

Example: assume the prompt is `Find file: /var/tmp/etc/list/foo/bar/`, then simply type `~/.emacs` to get the dot-emacs file in your home directory. No need to delete anything.

Comment: On Windows, you can type `~`, `/`, or `c:/` (where `c:` can be any drive letter) after the default pathname.

Answer (score 3):

You can use backward-kill-sentence that is bound by default to <kbd>M-DEL</kbd>

If you use ido-mode (if not you should give a try, it is very useful) you can just begin to type the path or name of the file you want to open and it will give you some proposals.

For the startup message, you can put the following in your .emacs :

```lisp
(setq inhibit-startup-message t)
```

Comment: `M-DEL` is `backward-kill-word` by default.

Comment: You are totally right, I made a confusion between `C-DEL` that also bind `backward-kill-word` in my emacs and `C-x DEL` for `backward-kill-sentence`

Comment: For what it's worth, if you want more emacs customization like the removal of the starting message or the replacement of yes/no by y/n for answers to emacs questions, you can take a look at my [own .emacs](http://sebastien.kirche.free.fr/emacs_stuff/en.html)

Answer (score 0):

The answers given are probably the best approach for now but once you've been using emacs for a while you should look at [ido-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings). Type `M-x ido-mode` to start, then use the arrow keys to move quickly around file paths.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use the following lisp code to kill the current line with a single key combination. This will remove the whole line and move to the cursor to the beginning.

```
(defun my-kill-line ()
  "kill current line. you don't have to put point at the beginning of line."
  (interactive)
  (copy-kill 'kill 'line))
```

A better approach (once you get familiar with Emacs usage) is to use some package to make your file navigation easier. Take a look to helm (or ido) I personally prefer helm and to projectile. Combining helm+projectile you can open files very fast and switch easily between files located on different directories/projects.